# "get window handle" command doesn't work on Microsoft Web Driver

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, windows-10, microsoft-edge

Environment:
- Window 10 : Insider Preview Build 10565. 
- Microsoft Web Driver : version 1.1 (build 10550)

I see "Get Window Handle" command which is available from build 10532. (https://dev.modern.ie/platform/status/webdriver/details/)
but i work on build 10565 still received error "Unknown command received"

Comment: can you post the code you are using?

Comment: I use HTTP request to send message to Microsoft Web Driver as {GET} "/session/{sessionId}/window/handle" . I get it from [link](https://dev.modern.ie/platform/status/webdriver/details/)

Comment: I know, you mentioned that. Can you please post the exact code you are using?

Comment: i don't use code. I use tool to send HTTP request with structure : GET "http://localhost:17556/session/{sessionId}/window/handle"

Comment: what tool do you use

Comment: I use webpage of Microsoft "https://dev.modern.ie/testdrive/demos/webdriver/"